# Filtering using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm using the programming language R to work on a repeated measures dataframe, `mydata`, whose first rows look like this:

```
ID    t    Variable_X

100096 0.0  0

100096 1.0  0

100026 0.0  1

100026 1.0  0

100036 0.0  0

100036 0.5  0

100036 1.0  0

100038 0.5  0

100041 0.0  0

100041 0.5  0

100041 1.0  0

100041 2.0  0

100041 3.0  0 

100041 3.5  0 

100083 0.0  0
```

As you can see, not all subjects (identified by their unique ID) have their first measurement at t=0.0. The subject assigned to the ID 100038 for example, has his first measurement at t 0.5; other subjects, not herewith displayed, have measurements taken at t 2 4 6 for example.

AIM: What I am trying to do is to retain for each subject only his first measurement. This I can achieve for individual subjects by applying the function `filter` from the `dplyr` package. Here is an example:

```
filter(mydata[mydata$ID==100026,],t==min(t))

ID    t    Variable_X

100026 0.0  1
```

PROBLEM: I would like to performe this as a loop and not have to do it manually for each ID. I've got the unique sequence of ID stored in a vector called `id_vec`. Thus printing id_vec would display:

```
100096 100026 100036 100038 100041 100083
```

I've tried the following code but it does't work:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=numeric(), t=numeric(), D3=numeric())

for(i in id_vec){
df[i]<-filter(mydata[mydata$ID==i,],t==min(t))
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What programming language is this ?

Comment: @TonyTannous The programming language I'm using is R.

Comment: You could do: `mydata %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)` to retain only the first measurement for each `ID`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré, that worked!!! Thank you very much!!! Guess I need to get more familiar with the dplyr package.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this here as an adjustment to what Steven posted. filtering by row_number() == 1 will filter by the first row, not by the minimum. If the first row in the group is the largest, it will still retain that. In order to filter by the minimum, do the below.

```
mydata %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(t == min(t)) %>%
    ungroup()
```